# How does the "Stop build" button work in Bamboo?

Tags: bamboo

[image]

How does the "Stop build" button work in Bamboo? I have a job that calls a Python3 script to run some tests on a machine. Does Bamboo send a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (SIGINT) to the process when "Stop build" is pressed? SIGKILL?

My script uses multiprocessing and has a graceful shutdown when it receives a SIGINT signal, but when I press "Stop build" it seems to kill the main process and let the rest of the processes keep living...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my Bamboo logs it appears that it sends a `SIGQUIT` signal followed by a `SIGTERM` signal five seconds later:

```
17:24:02    Executing kill -3 66265  # this sends SIGQUIT
17:24:07    Killing: 66265
17:24:07    Executing kill 66265 # this sends SIGTERM
```

By adding a signal handler like so I was able to catch it and gracefully exit my processes:

```
def signal_handler(self, signum, frame):
    print(f"Received a 'kill -{signum}'! Cleaning up...")
    self.cleanup()

# put these inside of the main function
signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, self.signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.signal_handler)
```

According to [this post on the Bamboo forums](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/What-happens-when-bamboo-stops-a-build/qaq-p/325860), Bamboo sends `SIGTERM` to the process but it doesn't mention the `SIGQUIT` that is sent first.

---

[image]

The above only seems to be true if you enable "Force stop build" in `Plan Configuration -> Other`. If "Force stop build" is not enabled then "Stop build" does not seem to do anything.